# Change variable in EXE or DLL

Tags: dll, exe, reverse-engineering, disassembly

I have a problem with a program which starts with one variable set to true by default. I need change this variable to false (so the program will start with this variable set to false). It is one EXE file with one DLL. Could you help me?

I have already tried: IDA, W32DASM but it is not successful to disassembly. Is it even possible?

Thank you all

Comment: Why it wasn't successful ? It should be an option. Please note there is another (tricky) option : use a tool to directly modify the variable in computer's memory once the program is started.

Comment: @Richard thank you for your reply. This variable has to be set before program started. Maybe it was successful but the data after disassembly gives me nothing useful. I guess, there's nothing where can I change this variable and save the change directly into EXE or its DLL? If yes could someone tell me how.
Thanks